# Request regarding one time authentication

Tags: uber-api

Greeting of the day!!!

We developing a web portal which will contain UBER car hire API services, our application’s screen shot I have attached here in which we have already integrated the UBER API for car and done the most of the development also.

Our main obstacle for now is dual authentication. First user come on our portal and register himself and then if he will user car hire service from here then he need to again login into the UBER site then he will able to use the service of it. But we need that application will user our database details and took user’s login details through which he login on portal and based on the same he can able to order the cab from Uber.

Kindly do provide the guidance for further that what we will do for this one time authentication. Currently we are affiliated partner of UBER but for further what process we need to do so, we can move further for the application as this is very critical issue for the business logic of the portal development and provide User UBER cab facility.

Kindly do guide us the details soon.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication) for a walkthrough to authenticate users with Uber's API.

When a user finishes authenticating you'll want to associate the `access_token` from the response in step 3 of that walkthrough.

To summarize

### 1. Ask the Uber user to log in to Uber and authorize your app

Send the user to Uber's OAuth page with the required params in the query string:

`https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?scope={{ scopes }}&response_type=code&client_id={{ client_id }}&redirect_uri={{ redirect_uri }}`

- Your `client_id` is available in the [developer dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard) under "Settings".
- The `redirect_uri` should correspond to the URI you register in the developer dashboard under "Authorizations".
- The `scopes` should correspond to the same boxes you checked below the form where you retrieved your redirect URI., e.g. `request+profile+history`.

### 2. Get an authorization code when the user is redirected

After logging in with Uber and authorizing your app, the user will be sent to your redirect URI. The URI's query string will include a `code` parameter. This is the user's authorization code. In the next step you will send it back to Uber in exchange for the access token that you need to make requests on behalf of this user. Save this authorization code for the next step.

### 3. Exchange that code for an access token

Send an HTTP POST request to `https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token`. Include the following JSON body:

`{
      "client_secret": "{{ client_secret }}",
      "client_id": "{{ client_id }}",
      "grant_type": "authorization_code",
      "redirect_uri": "{{ redirect_uri }}",
      "code": "{{ insert authorization code obtained in previous step }}"
}`

### 4. Use the access token to make requests on the user's behalf.

The value under the `access_token` field in the response to the request in step 3 is what you need to make requests to Uber on behalf of that user. Include an `Authorization: Bearer {{ access_token }}` header in all requests on behalf of that user. You'll want to save this token in a database so that your user does not need to go through the OAuth flow every time they want to use your app.

Example request with an access token, using cURL:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer {{ access_token }}" https://api.uber.com/v1/me`

(Note: This request only works if you have successfully asked your user to grant the `profile` scope to your app.)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you, I added a summary.